# how am I supposed to export fbx only one mesh>?

Tags: export

I have like 6 objects in different layers but then when I want to export only one of them, I happen to export all of them.

Any means?

Answer (score 1):

In Object mode select the mesh you want to export. 
File > Export > FBX (.fbx).  Then in the FBX export window enable "Selected Objects".

[image]

Only selected objects will be exported.

Answer (score 0):

blender export only mesh, File > Export > FBX > select include enable only mesh > disable
bake animation. Completed
[image]